# Command to check if RAID 1 or not?

Tags: raid

I am a newbie on Linux.

I buy one new dedicate server and now checking my hardware from CENTOS console.

Could you tell me how to check if my server has an RAID 1 configured?

many thanks

Comment: Typically you check the specs of a server before you buy... How to confirm if you got what was promised depends on what was promised in the first place.

Comment: hi, it means I can not use command to view my server has RAID or not?

Comment: There isn't a generic method to determine if you are using a hardware RAID.  But there are methods to manage certain RAID controllers from software.  Update your question with the output of `lshw -class storage -class disk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OS is running directly on the hardware and you believe you have a hardware-based RAID the first step would be to use a tool like `lshw` to discover the type of Storage/RAID controller. After you have learned that you would probably need to do some Googling to find the software tools required to manage that RAID controller from your OS.

If this was a simple software RAID then just look at your `/proc/mdstat`.